# ConcurrentModificationException in CXF during performance testing

Tags: java, cxf

Exception below was found during performance testing.

CXF v3.0.0

JDK v1.8.92

PolicyInInterceptor.java:74 is the following code:

```
Policy p = (Policy)msg.getContextualProperty(PolicyConstants.POLICY_OVERRIDE);
```

So looks like interceptor tried to manipulate Hashmap data (with Exchanges?).

We already using this option:

```
 getRequestContext().put("thread.local.request.context", "true");
```

from this [CXF FAQ](http://cxf.apache.org/faq.html#FAQ-AreJAX-WSclientproxiesthreadsafe?) but with no any changes in stacktrace.

Checked list of issue in [CFX jira](https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-4407?jql=project%20%3D%20CXF%20AND%20resolution%20in%20(Unresolved%2C%20Fixed%2C%20Duplicate%2C%20Later%2C%20Implemented%2C%20Done%2C%20%22Auto%20Closed%22%2C%20%22Pending%20Closed%22%2C%20Resolved%2C%20Workaround)%20AND%20text%20~%20%22ConcurrentModificationException%22). Found nothing similar.

Any advice?

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Fault string, and possibly fault code, not set 
   at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:159)
   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy281.reqVirtualAcct(Unknown Source) 
   at com.mycompanyname.vc.vpp.VService.requestCFP(VService.java:240)
   at com.mycompanyname.vc.vpp.VService.requestC(VService.java:216)
   at com.mycompanyname.vc.vpp.VService.requestC(VService.java:105) 
   at com.mycompanyname.payment.PaymentSI.requestAndPopulateVC(PaymentSI.java:959) 
   at com.mycompanyname.payment.PaymentSI.createPayment(PaymentSI.java:669)
   at com.mycompanyname.payment.PaymentSI.createPayment(PaymentSI.java:2099)
   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor641.invoke(Unknown Source) 
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) 
   at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333) 
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) 
   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy228.createPayment(Unknown Source)
   at com.mycompanyname.paymentws.PSaaSOrderPortTypeV3Impl.createP(PSaaSOrderPortTypeV3Impl.java:148)
   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor880.invoke(Unknown Source) 
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
   at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) 
   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy260.createPayable(Unknown Source) 
   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor880.invoke(Unknown Source) 
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
   at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:181) 
   at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:97) 
   at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.java:237) 
   at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(JAXWSMethodInvoker.java:69)
   at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:75) 
   at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) 
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
   at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$2.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:126) 
   at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37) 
   at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:131)
   at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307) 
   at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
   at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:243)
   at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:223) 
   at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:197)
   at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.filter(ServletController.java:146) 
   at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.doFilter(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:144) 
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) 
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) 
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169) 
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) 
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.StuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(StuckThreadDetectionValve.java:220) 
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962) 
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) 
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445) 
   at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:190) 
   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) 
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) 
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
   at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode(HashMap.java:1442)
   at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:1476) 
   at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:1474) 
   at java.util.HashMap.putMapEntries(HashMap.java:512) 
   at java.util.HashMap.putAll(HashMap.java:785) 
   at org.apache.cxf.message.MessageImpl$1.putAll(MessageImpl.java:188)
   at org.apache.cxf.message.MessageImpl.calcContextCache(MessageImpl.java:212) 
   at org.apache.cxf.message.MessageImpl.getContextualProperty(MessageImpl.java:174)
   at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyInInterceptor.handle(PolicyInInterceptor.java:74)
   at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AbstractPolicyInterceptor.handleMessage(AbstractPolicyInterceptor.java:44)
   at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
   at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:798) 
   at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1636)
   at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1525)
   at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1330) 
   at org.apache.cxf.io.CacheAndWriteOutputStream.postClose(CacheAndWriteOutputStream.java:56) 
   at org.apache.cxf.io.CachedOutputStream.close(CachedOutputStream.java:215) 
   at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56) 
   at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:638)
   at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
   at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
   at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:514) 
   at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:423)
   at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:326) 
   at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:279)
   at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
   at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:137) 
 ... 59 more
```

---

**Update**

This question was moved to "on hold":

> "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?")
>   must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the
>   shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.
>   Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other
>   readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example."

This question is not "why isn't this code working?". This question is "why isn't this code working in very specific case with exception somewhere in dependency?" Specific case is performance testing. In all other cases this code is working fine.

"shortest code necessary to reproduce" is a problem, because performance testing is test on real system so there are no any code for reproduce. Anyway I tried to reproduce it with no luck.

So Im still thinking original question has enough context and description. 
Btw despite that question was asked during weekend I got two up vote on it.

Comment: My guess is you're hitting a race condition from hitting it hard with messages from your performance test, resulting in it's still trying to its initial-load of its cache from processing the first message when the second message comes in.  Maybe try modifying your performance test to fire the first half-dozen messages slowly before unleashing the torrent (and do something similar as part of your release process)

Comment: @racraman it makes sense. we will check this case. thanks